# using an apply function to run a function with a vector that returns a single value

Tags: r

is there a way to use an apply function when taking a vector and returning a single value? For example I have a vector and I would like to return the mean of that vector. The only reason I do not want to use mean() is because I want to be able choose different functions to be able to apply to the vector.

For example

```
vec <- c(1,2,3,4,5) 
fun <- function(vec, function){

apply(vec , function)

}

fun(vec, mean)
```

when using something like lapply or sapply, it applies the function to each individual entry in the vector, rather than running the function for the whole vector. I guess I’m either looking for a way to use either lap ply or sapply and apply the function to the row instead of the column, or a new function that can do this.

Comment: I thought you just run out of reduce, you were already describing R.

Answer (score 5):

In R one can pass a function and then invoke it; however, one cannot have a parameter named `function` since that is a reserved word -- try `?Reserved` to see them all -- so we call it `func`.

```
fun <- function(vec, func) func(vec)

fun(1:3, mean)
## [1] 2

fun(1:3, sum)
## [1] 6
```

Typically this is written using `match.fun` so that either `mean` or `"mean"` can be passed.

```
fun2 <- function(vec, func) {
  func <- match.fun(func)
  func(vec)
}

fun2(1:3, mean)
## [1] 2

fun2(1:3, "mean")
## [1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Really appreciate it